# Verificacion de campos en cada input con python

Tags: python

Se trata de pedir informacion de nombre, fecha de nacimiento, direccion y metas personales
si los campos cumplen con los campos introducidos se le pregunta la siguiente pregunta, si no se le vuelve a preguntar la misma pregunta

el campo de nombre tiene que ser solo de letras, el de fecha numeros y letras, direccion igual que el de fecha y metas personales igual

```
import re

nombre=input("ingrese su nombre por favor: ")
if re.match("^[a-zA-Z_ ]*", nombre):
        fecha_nacimiento = input("introduzca fecha nacimiento: ")
        if re.match("^[A-Za-z0-9]*", fecha_nacimiento):
            direccion = input("cual es su direccion: ")
            if re.match("^[A-Za-z0-9_ ]*", direccion):
                metasPersonales=input("ingrese metas personales: ")
                if re.match("^[A-Za-z0-9_ ]*", metasPersonales):
                    print(f'su informacion completa es: Nombre: ', nombre, 'fecha nacimiento:', fecha_nacimiento, 'direccion:',direccion, 'y metas personales:', metasPersonales)
                else:
                    metasPersonales = input("ingrese metas personales, nuevamente: ")
            else:
                direccion = input("cual es su direccion nuevamente: ")

        else:
            fecha_nacimiento = input("introduzca fecha nacimiento correcta: ")

else:
        print("hay un error, nombre incorrecto")
        nombre = input("ingrese su nombre correcto, por favor: ")
```

sin embargo si coloco numeros en los campos me sigue preguntando y no deberia ser asi
ya intente con el metodo is.alpha() y is.digit() pero no funcionan

Comment: Probe el programa y funciona de acuerdo con lo esperado. Excepto `nombre`, todos los campos aceptan dígitos como respuesta. ¿Con que combinación de campos "no funciona"?

Comment: coloque puros numeros y simbolos en nombre y me pregunta la siguiente pregunta, la de la fecha de nacimiento, no deberia ser si no cumple

Answer (score 1):

El problema es el uso del calificador "*" en lugar de "+".

El "*" después de un patrón calza **cero** o más veces. Eso quiere decir que cualquier texto va a calzar con el patrón:

```
nombre = "1234"
if re.match("^[a-zA-Z_ ]*", nombre):
    print(nombre, "calza")
```

produce:

```
1234 calza

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**Solución**

Emplear el calificador adecuado: "+" obliga a calzar al menos una vez:

```
if re.match("[a-zA-Z_ ]+", nombre):
```

Además, `match` calza sólo al comienzo del texto, por lo que es redundamente empezar el patrón con "^".

*Nota*

El patrón "[a-zA-Z_ ]+" también reconoce un nombre en blanco. ¿Tal vez sería "[a-zA-Z_]+"

Comment: ok voy a probar, podrias compartirme una pagina donde explique un poco mejor eso, por favor ? ya que no sabria como googlearlo

Comment: @anonymuus_gp. Busca "tutorial expresion regular python". También puedes mirar la documentación https://docs.python.org/es/3.8/howto/regex.html

Comment: Okay gracias por compartir! y me sirvio! muchas gracias